# SignalR multi-room session

Tags: signalr

SignalR multi-room session

My application is as follows
The user sees the rooms on the login screen. When he chooses one of the rooms and types his username, he logs into that room.
Rooms are formed as follows eg:
[www.domain.com/room/1](http://www.domain.com/room/1)
[www.domain.com/room/2](http://www.domain.com/room/2)
Then he texts with other users in the room.

My question is as follows:

When a user connected to a room opens the room link in a different tab, a new "Context.ConnectionId" value is assigned, so the room is created from the beginning. I want the connection to continue as it connects to the same room even if it's on a different tab.

In addition, a user should be able to be in both room1 and room2 at the same time, if he / she wishes.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You want to look into using "Groups" in SignalR. Users can, depending on your design, open a new tab, log in and join a different room. They will get messages through both in their respective room.

```
public async Task JoinRoom(string roomName)
{
    await Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, roomName);
    Clients.Group(roomName).addChatMessage(Context.User.Identity.Name + " joined.");
}
```

Reference Documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups

Comment: I partially resolved the problem. Yes, I use groups, but as I said, groups do not work exactly as I want them to.
If it comes to a solution:
I created a special key for that room for every user who enters the room and I keep this key in the localstorage. (eg: localStorage.setItem ('room_1', unique_id);)
Even if the user enters from another tab, I understand that he is the same user in the same room when the user is checked on the localstorage side and it is clear that that key exists.
Of course, I keep these keys in redis on the Hub side.